# Asp.net user control changing language on texts

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I'm working on a asp.net website and I have created a user control where I've placed a menu to be used on the master page. Now I want to be able to change the language on each menu item by using a resource file. How do I change this on a user control? I've worked it out on a regular aspx-page but ascx workes different as it derives from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you do it on the aspx page? You can go into design mode, select generate local resources and the resx file will be generated for you. For User Controls it works the same way as for ASP.NET web forms.